# How can I login to Cisco WLC GUI using Ansible playbook with Username and Password and get an Output?

Tags: ansible, uri

I am trying to write an Ansible-Playbook to Login to Cisco WLC using Web GUI and get an Output from it. I am using Ansible uri module to do that, while running the code it get the Main page but can see if it is able to login or not. Please help.

```
- name: Login to WLC and Return webpage
  hosts: WLC
  connection: local
  gather_facts: flase


  tasks:

    - name: Login to Cisco WLC using web GUI
      uri:
        url: https://10.23.201.2
        method: GET
        force_basic_auth: yes
        url_username: username
        url_password: password
        validate_certs: False
        return_content: yes
        register: login
    - debug: var=login.stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`aireos_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aireos_command_module.html) module. For example, if you wanted to get the output for the `show wlan summary` command, you should create something like this:

```
- name: show wlan summary
  aireos_command:
    provider:
      host: '{{inventory_hostname}}'
      username: '{{username}}'
      password: '{{password}}'
      timeout: 30
    commands: 
      - show wlan summary
  register: output
```

Then, if you wanted to parse the output and convert it into another data type, you can use the [`parse_cli`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#network-cli-filters) filter. Here is an example of how you could parse the output:

```
- set_fact:
  data: '{{ output["stdout"][0] | parse_cli("./specs/wlan_summary.yml") }}'
```

And inside the `./specs/wlan_summary.yml`:

```
---
vars:
  wlan:
    wlc_id: '{{ item.wlc_id }}'
    state: '{{item.state}}'
    interface: '{{ item.interface }}'
    profile: '{{ item.profile }}'
    ssid: '{{ item.ssid }}'

keys:
  items:
    value: "{{ wlan }}"
    items: "^(?P<wlc_id>\\d)\\s+(?P<profile>.*?)\\s/\\s(?P<ssid>.*?)\\s{2,}(?P<state>\\w+)\\s+(?P<interface>\\w+)"
```

I hope it helps.